# Плавное появление элемента при удаление класса с дисплей ноне

Tags: javascript, css

Необходимо сделать плавное появление(анимацию) блока.

Есть див у него 2 класса Класс1 и класс2

```
ccs
Класс1{
    background: #363C3E;
    z-index: 2;}
Класс2{
    display: none;}
```

При нажатии на кнопку js удаляет класс2 из блока, и разумеется мгновенно блок становится видным. Немногу понять, как сделать плавное появление, например растяжение или еще что-то.
Высота блока предварительно не определенна